# MS SQL отправка отчета на почту с помощью sp_send_dbmail строка вида ------ сразу после заголовка

Tags: sql-server

Настраиваю отправку отчета по почте. Ниже представлен код. Все работает, но при открытии в excel со второй строкой происходит такая история, как на картинке ниже, в целом с данными все в порядке.

[image: Пример того, что происходит со 2-й строкой]

Код:

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'Profile'
        ,@recipients = 'mail@mail.com'
        ,@query = @qry
        ,@subject = 'subject'
        ,@body = 'body'
        ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1
        ,@query_attachment_filename = 'Report.csv'
        ,@query_result_header = 1
        ,@query_result_separator = @tab
        ,@exclude_query_output = 1    
        ,@query_no_truncate = 0
        ,@append_query_error = 1
        ,@query_result_no_padding = 1
        ;
```

Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1) Можно попробовать отключить заголовки в параметрах (@ query_result_header = 0), а затем вывести заголовки первой строкой:

```
SELECT 'Column1Name', 'Column2Name', 'Column3Name'
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM MyTable
```

Это конечно костыль, но рабочий.

2) Установить `@query_result_width=500`, пишут помогает.

Comment: 1) - если писать через UNION - строка с заголовками в конец уезжает,
приходится делать что-то вроде  ORDER BY (case when Id='Id' then '0' else Id end);
2) - не помогло!